# proof that $a_n$ is a null sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove, that $a_n$ is a null sequence if $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|= c < 1$$

That means that $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n \ge N: |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - c| < \epsilon$

How can I get rid of the $a_{n+1}$ and the $c$, to show $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n \ge N: |a_n| < \epsilon$

?

Comment: Could you please explain what is null sequence.

Comment: @janak: Just googled. It's a sequence with limit $0$. (So I can also define $\pi$-sequence, $e$-sequence etc...)

Comment: Thought it would be the normal english word... Sorry :D $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|= 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution: for $n$ large enough
$$0\le|a_{n+1}|\le|a_n|,$$
i.e., $(|a_n|)_{n\ge n_0}$ is bounded and monotonic. Let be $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|\ge 0$. If $l\ne 0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \frac{l}{l} = 1\ne c.$$
Finally,
$$
0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n|\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|= c < 1
$$
implies that $|a_{n+1}| \le b |a_{n}|$ for $n\ge N$ and $b=(c+1)/2 < 1$.
Therefore,
$|a_{n}| \le b^{n-N} |a_{N}|$ for $n\ge N$. Since $|b|<1$, we have $b^n\to 0$.

Comment: How did u get to $b = (c+1)/2$ ?

Comment: @Rummelluff, the precise value is not important; just some $b$ with $c<b<1$. Think of $b$ as $c+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean that $a_n$ is vanishing at $\infty$. Anyway if $\lim\frac{a_n}{a_{+1}}=c<1$ then you have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. By force the sequence $a_n$ must be vanishing at $\infty$. (See Ceraro theorem)

Comment: That's overkill.

Comment: :) you're right, but the one line solutions are very funny!

Comment: But you have two lines :)

Answer (score 1):

This statement can be proven by providing the proof of the Ratio Test:

> **Ration Test**
>
> To apply the Ratio Test to a given infinite series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$, we evaluate the limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg|=L$$
>   There are 3 possibilities:
>
> 1. If $L<1$, then the series converges
> 2. If $L>1$, then the series diverges
> 3. If $L=1$, then the test is inconclusive

In order to prove your given statement, we are interested in Possibility 1.

**Proof (Of Possibility 1)**

Our aim here is to compare the given series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ with  a convergent Geometric Series.

Since we have that $L<1$, we may choose any number $r$ such that $L<r<1.$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg|=L,\ \ \  L<r$
the ratio $\displaystyle \bigg|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg|$ will eventually be less than $r$. In other words, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\displaystyle \bigg|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg| < r$, whenever $k\geq 0$.

This follows from the formal definition of the limit (Try and see how).

Rearrangement then yields $$\bigg|a_{k+1}\bigg|< \bigg | a_k \bigg|r, \ \ \text{whenever $k \geq N$}$$
If we let $k$ equal $N, N+1, N+2$ in the previous equation we obtain \begin{align}\bigg|a_{N+1}\bigg| &< \bigg | a_N \bigg|r \\ \bigg|a_{N+2}\bigg|&< \bigg | a_{N+1} \bigg|r \\ \bigg|a_{N+3}\bigg|&< \bigg | a_{N+2} \bigg|r\end{align}
which in general, gives $$\bigg|a_{N+k}\bigg|< \bigg | a_N \bigg|r^k , \ \ \ \text{whenever $k \geq 1$}$$
Then the series $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_N|r^k = |a_N|r + |a_{N+1}|r^2 + |a_{N+2}|r^3 + ...$$
converges, since it is a geometric series with $0<r<1$.

Thus we can conclude, by the Comparison Test, that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|= |a_{N+1}|+|a_{N+2}|+|a_{N+3}|+...$$
is convergent, and so our given series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is also convergent since adding a finite number of terms to a convergent series, still results in a convergent series.
Therefore, we know our series is absolutely convergent (and also convergent).

Since we have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely, we know $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converges.

Thus we have that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} |a_k|= 0 \iff\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k= 0 $$
Which proves our given theorem.